# Problem with jQuery post to ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have gone through this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113597/asp-net-core-2-jquery-post-data-null) on stackoverflow but I couldn't solve my problem.

In **HomeController** I have a method named as **Audit** which I want to be posted from /Home/Index page's script through jQuery. The controller looks like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

  public JsonResult Audit([FromBody] JObject jObject)
  {
       if (jObject != null)
       {
           return Json("success");
       }
       return Json("failed");
  }
}
```

In the /Home/Index pages's javascript file I have tried to post a JSON Object to that Audit in a way like this:

```
var auditData = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
    var request = $.getJSON('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp', function (responseData, status) {
        auditData = {
            Latitude : responseData.geoplugin_latitude,
            Longitude : responseData.geoplugin_longitude
        };

        $.post('Audit', auditData, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

I want the auditData object to be posted as JObject in /Home/Audit but something is going wrong. I think there is problem either in controller or, in **$.post** method. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you debugged the request to see what the error is? I can see you're not passing an anti-forgery token, so that attribute will be causing issues if nothing else

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Debugging says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There's your first issue then. The `'Audit'` path isn't valid. I'd suggest trying `'/Home/Audit'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your current code, check points below one by one:

1. As the suggestion from Rory, your request url is wrong, which should be `Home/Audit`
2. If you post request without antitoken, you should remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`
3. You should post request data with json instead of form data.

Code:

Client

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var auditData = {};
        $(document).ready(function(){
                auditData = {
                    Latitude : "l1",
                    Longitude : "l2"
                };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Home/Audit',
                data: JSON.stringify(auditData),
                success: function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Server:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public JsonResult Audit([FromBody]JObject jObject)
    {
        if (jObject != null)
        {
            return Json("success");
        }
        return Json("failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post URL is wrong, and you need to name the data you're posting back as `jObject` as well to match what you defined in your controller.

```js
$.post('@Url.Action("audit", "home", new { area = "" })', { jObject: auditData }, 
  function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```